# i want to prevent Exponential in my floating value in java

Tags: java

i want to prevent Exponential in my floating value in java

```html
 float datapoint=9.0E-4;
    
    but i want to print this"9.0" only
```

please any one help!!

Comment: `9.0`?  But that's not what the number represents.

Comment: Why would you want to print "9.0" when the value is 0.0009?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the DecimalFormat

```
Float f = 9.0E-4f;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
System.out.println(df.format(f));
```

Comment: Thanq very much Rahul

Comment: @ChanduD:- You are welcome. Just to add that the other solution will give you just 9.0 which is incorrect as 9.0 != 0.0009.

Comment: actually i want to show 9.0 only so i don't want exact value

Comment: @ChanduD:- Thats strange, anyways that is not the standard way. Anyways you can proceed with whatever solution worked for you! :)

Comment: @chandu whay you need to print 9.0 from 9.0E-4. These two are not same. Rahul's answer is more appropriate one

Comment: yes i agree with both of u just am showing on my y-axis and then i have to provide scaling those values

Comment: finally your method is coincide what my exact requirement thousands of thanks rahul

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code snippet -

```
public class PrintFloat{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Float f = 9.0E-4f;
        String str = Float.toString(f);
        String[] array = str.split("E");
        System.out.println(array[0]);
    }
}
```

But 9.0E-4 and 9.0 are not the same value.